# PreSaveAction on a ListInstance with a custom ContentType

Tags: 2013, visual-studio, content-type, custom-list, list-form

Everything I've read about PreSaveAction requires me to edit the NewForm or EditForm to add the reference into the form.  However, given my list is created from Visual Studio using a custom content type and list instance - I don't want to also go down the route of creating a custom form for each of my lists and having to maintain them too.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do on PreSaveAction, maybe you can replace it with Event Receiver or Custom Field Control with Validations ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create custom form for your lists. You can create a JavaScript file and override `PreSaveAction` in it. Then in the Schema file you can add `JSLink` attribute to to the `Form` tag in NewForm.aspx or any other form. Example:

```
<Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" JSLink="~site/Scripts/ShowHideField.js" />
```

Comment: I'd gone down the route of using JSLink on the field itself to validate it, I didnt know it could be used on the form itself.

Comment: Doesn't look like its working with my version of `SP2013`/`VS2012`.  `JSLink` works fine in the `CustomField` but not in the form tag in `schema.xml`.

Comment: I have used it myself and works well. Make sure you are providing the correct path.

Comment: You can also check by setting the Physical path like /_layouts/15/Scripts/ShowHideField.js

Comment: I think there was a JS issue, thanks it does work even though VS doesnt like it.

Comment: Thanks, it works but I also figured out how to use validation in the list schema anyway.