# Executing JavaScript when item is being saved

Tags: sharepoint-addin, app, sharepoint-hosted-app, jslink

I have my custom EditForm created in my SharePoint-hosted app and I need to save some values to the item property bag when the user clicks "Save" button. Is there any way to modify the default saving behaviour with JSLinks or something? If not, is there any way to create some kind of client event-receiver which runs after item is being modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `PreSaveAction` override using JavaScript.

[PreSaveAction on a ListInstance with a custom ContentType](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/90702/presaveaction-on-a-listinstance-with-a-custom-contenttype)